# SQL SERVER TRANSACTION LOG

Tags: sql, sql-server

what are the consequences if the Transaction log growth is restricted and full in SQL SERVER

Answer (score 2):

It will explodes and burn down your house..

Seriously , it will generate problems such as, not being able to perform transaction.

Answer (score 1):

**I strongly agree with Kundan.
But would like add some more points on this:**

> Additionally, transaction log expansion may occur for one of the
>   following reasons or in one of the following scenarios:

1. A very large transaction log file.
2. Transactions may fail and may start to roll back.
3. Transactions may take a long time to complete.
4. Performance issues may occur.
5. Blocking may occur.
6. The database is participating in an AlwaysOn availability group.

> You can take following actions i the log file is full:

1. Backing up the log.
2. Freeing disk space so that the log can automatically grow.
3. Moving the log file to a disk drive with sufficient space.
4. Increasing the size of a log file.
5. Adding a log file on a different disk.
6. Completing or killing a long-running transaction.

For more info please refer to the below mentioned link:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/317375/a-transaction-log-grows-unexpectedly-or-becomes-full-in-sql-server

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175495.aspx